# File Path to Drive E with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a script installed in D:\ wich contain javascript to load PDF.
I need to declare Physical Path to read file, in this way:

```
fileName = "D:/Storage/test.pdf";
```

I'm experiencing a trouble when i move Storage folder to E:\ Drive, file couldn't read.

Seem because script is in D:\ and Storage in E:\ (different drive)

```
fileName = "E:/Storage/test.pdf";
```

Any suggestion to solve?

Comment: You have two times the same line of code, and no mention of `E:` there. Did it work when you used the full path to `D:\`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not good making this, the only reason is a personal application in your physical PC, but if you need it, you can solve adding the protocol file

```
 fileName = "file://D:/Storage/test.pdf";
```

Protocols can be:

```
file://
http://
https://
ftp://
webdav://
```

And tons of more protocols.